# Apache Camel: How to copy CSV content to txt file using XML Dsl syntax?

Tags: csv, apache-camel

I would like to copy the mock_data.csv content to file.txt.
I'm able to do it with java syntax:

```
from("file:D:?fileName=USER_MOCK.csv&noop=true").to("file:D:?fileName=file.txt");
```

I would like to do it throught XML syntax, what I've done is that:

```
        <route id="_route1">
            <from id="route" uri="file:D:?fileName=MOCK_DATA.csv;noop=true"/>
            <to uri="file:D:?fileName=file.txt"/>
        </route>
```

What's wrong?

**EDIT:**
Solved removing ";noop=true" but now I got new error. Route repeat itself many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escape the ampersand `&` by `&amp;` as state [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-use-uris-with-parameters-in-xml.html)

```
<route id="_route1">
    <from id="route" uri="file:D:?fileName=MOCK_DATA.csv&amp;noop=true"/>
    <to uri="file:D:?fileName=file.txt"/>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many camel components have polling mechanism so that means watches given directory. You can have it read once with the repeatcount parameter.

```
from("file:D:?fileName=USER_MOCK.csv&repeatCount=1")
        .to("file:D:?fileName=file.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you but im trying to deal with XML syntax.